# Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm) in groovy script

Tags: sql-server, groovy

i have a groovy script that connect to MSSQL database, a few week ago it works very nice, but today i had upload a last version of mac os, and my script give me this exception:

```
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: GSS Failed: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: GSS Failed: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:654)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at getMarque.run(getMarque.groovy:3)
```

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps a little late.

I had the same error, when I was trying to connect to the database with an empty string as username and password.

After I added a username and password the error disappeared.

Comment: I misspelled "username" as "user"