# Connect SQL Server to MapR-Talend Sandbox

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sandbox, talend, mapr

I am new to Talend.
I have installed my MapR + Talend sandbox. Now I may want to try to connect my local MS SQL Server to the Talend in the sandbox. Unfortunately when I try to create the db connection, it showed error like this:
[image]

I downloaded the jdbc driver in my local windows and ubuntu. Can someone tell me how to install the driver and where should I put/install the jdbc driver in both windows and ubuntu?

Comment: It seems that the driver is loaded fine, since the error message is already concerning MS SQL Server. Maybe add explicit username and password as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378533/invalid-name-provided-mechanism-level-krbexception-cannot-locate-default-real

Comment: Please post exception stacktraces as **text**, not as screenshots